# Can the siunitx table alignment feature, S, align ratios?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'd like to align a list of ratios in a column of a table by the colon. Is this possible using `siunitx`?

For instance ratios like the following.

1:0.9

1:1.0125

1:0.99

Comment: If the first part of the ratio is always `1:` then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. What setting do I need to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helpful options are:

- `table-space-text-pre` and
- `table-align-text-pre`.

You need the set a dummy text with the `-space-` option, so `siunitx` can reserve the right space in front of the actual number.

The `-align-` option accepts `true` (default) or `false` and sets the alignment of the text (see example).

We only want `1.0` part so be typeset by `siunitx`, the `1` from `1:` would confuse the parer; we need to hide it in braces: `{1:}` or `{1}:`.

As you can see in the last table, we can even use different numbers in front of `:` (though, as it currently stands, they will not be typeset by `siunitx`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-format=2.4,table-space-text-pre=1:}
\begin{tabular}{>{{1}:}S}
    0.9    \\
    1.0125 \\
    0.99   \\
    13.0 
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}{>{{1}:}S[table-align-text-pre=false]}
    0.9    \\
    1.0125 \\
    0.99   \\
    13.0 
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}{S}
    {1:}0.9    \\
    {2:}1.0125 \\
    {3:}0.99   \\
    {4:}13.0 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]