# How to correctly use siunitx to align number in the center of a table for number with preamble

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I would like to have my numbers aligned left but centered in a table as in this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9203/how-to-align-integers-on-the-right-but-still-center-them), which I also tried to apply. Now my numbers are of the form `~24%`. For a correct alignment I tried to protect the non-number parts by writing it as `{$\sim$}24{ \%}`. The `%` is well behind the number, however the `~` is centered in the column and overlapping the numbers. Same thing happens when using something like `{xx}60{ \%}` where now the `xx` and the numbers overlap. How to protect the `~` to stay left of the number?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.0]}
     \toprule
      & {Before treatment} & {After treatment} \\
      \midrule
     component1 & {$\sim$}60{ \%} & {$\sim$}15{ \%} \\
     component2 & {$\sim$}14{ \%} & {$\sim$}4{ \%} \\
     component3 & {$\sim$}26{ \%} & {$\sim$}81{ \%} \\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `table-space-text-*` options. Can you provide a sample table? For `\sim` for a `~`, please see [How does one insert a backslash or a tilde (~) into LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363) On that note, `\sim` is also allowed as input-comparator so it shouldn’t be a problem if you properly declare the comparator usage for that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comment, the `table-space-text-post` option helps with saving the right space after the number. To stay with `siunitx` default setting, the thin space `\,` is used instead of a full space.

The `\sim` macro is already one of the allowed input macros of `siunitx` and is used as a comparator. This allows you to use `\sim` without any protection in the column. The space for it is allocated with the `table-comparator` switch, or, for the special `table-format` option with an `<` (or `>` or …?) in front of the integer part.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l *2{S[table-format=<2.0, table-space-text-post=\,\%]}}
    \toprule
               & {Before treatment} & {After treatment} \\ \midrule
    component1 & \sim 60 \,\%       & \sim 15 \,\%      \\
    component2 & \sim 14 \,\%       & \sim 4  \,\%      \\
    component3 & \sim 26 \,\%       & \sim 81 \,\%      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If I would use some text like `xx` before the number, then it would have to be done with `table-space-text-pre`?

Comment: @user2758804 Correct. For more information, check out the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf#page=46), and for examples, see [Can the siunitx table alignment feature, S, align ratios?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102364)