# Placing a symbol before a table entry without upsetting alignment by the siunitx package

Tags: tables, siunitx

In the following MWE, I use the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package to align numerical entries in a table. How can I place a `\sim` symbol before the "6" without upsetting the alignment?  Table A will compile; Table B will not.

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

% A
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & 6\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A}
\end{table}

% B
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & \sim 6\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math} 
\usepackage[expansion = false,
            tracking = smallcaps,
            letterspace = 40,
            final]  {microtype}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c
                  S[input-comparators,              % <----
                    table-space-text-pre=$\sim$,    % <----
                    table-format=1.1,
                    ]          
                 }
    \toprule
type    &   {X}         \\
    \midrule
A       & $\sim$ 6      \\
B       &        0.1    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{A}
    \end{table}
    
\medskip
    
\medskip
however, in table is better to use 

\verb+table-comparator+ instead of \verb+input-comparators+ as suggested in @Bernard's answer:

\medskip
  \begin{tabular}{c
                  S[table-format=1.1,
                    table-space-text-pre=$\sim$,
                    table-comparator]   % <----
                 }
    \toprule
type    &   {X}     \\
    \midrule
A       & \sim 6    \\                  % <----
B       & 0.1       \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

In both examples result is the same:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

To add symbols, you have the key `input-symbols`, but this one is a comparator, so you just have to set the `table-comparator` switch to true:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false, table-comparator]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & \sim 6\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been reading your horoscope for the new year and it looks like it starts for you with a great event: LOTS of points and lots of happiness! AHAHAHAHAHH.

Comment: @Sebastiano: How that? You do not draw horoscopes yourself? I'm terribly disappointed… ;o)

Answer (score 3):

Put the `\SI{\sim 6}{}` instead of `\sim` and it is works in `pdfLaTeX`. Happy new year :-).
See the explanation here: [How to correctly use siunitx to align number in the center of a table for number with preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145647/how-to-correctly-use-siunitx-to-align-number-in-the-center-of-a-table-for-number)

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

% A
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & 6\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A}
\end{table}

% B
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & \SI{\sim 6}{}
\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit by comment**:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

% A
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & 6\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A}
\end{table}

% B
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format=1.1,table-number-alignment=left,table-align-text-post=false]
}
    \toprule
    & {X}\\
    \midrule
    A & \!\!\!\SI{\sim 6}{}
\\
    B & 0.1\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the "6" no longer lines up with the "0". Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: @Andrew I understand the English language very bit. Use a trick :-). See `\!\!\!\SI{\sim 6}{}` if it is good for you without to change anything.